# Is this an equation of a circle?

Tags: circles

Wanted to know why the following equation doesn't represent a circle:

$2x^2 + 2y^2 − 6x + 4y + 7 = 0$

I know that $(\frac{-a}{2})^2 + (\frac{-b}{2})^2 - c \geq 0$

And it is, but the exercise says it doesn't represent a circle :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you complete squares you would get
\begin{equation}
\left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2+\left(y+1\right)^2=-\frac{1}{4}
\end{equation}
It would mean that the circle has a radius equal to $r=\sqrt{-1/4}$, which is imaginary. So, it is not an equation of a circle.

Comment: Completely right. Forgot to divide the whole equation by 2, thank you! Having the test tomorrow, will let you know how it went ;)

Comment: Hey! The test was great at last ahaha, got an 8/10 in Math that year (my teacher is quite tough)!

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is equivalent to:

$x^2+y^2-3 x+2y=-\frac{7}{2}$

Now add to both sides so as to complete the squares on the left hand side.  Think about what you end up with on the right hand side.

Comment: Absolutely right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because this doesn't satisfy the g² +f² -c > 0 condition which an equation of the form x² +y² +2 gx +2 fy +c = 0 must to represent a circle.